# Pointwise convergence of convex functions $\implies$ there exists pointwise convergence of their tangents?

Tags: real-analysis, tangent-line

Let $(f_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of convex functions converging pointwise to another convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that at some point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, all the functions $(f_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}},f$ have tangents. I define a tangent $l:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ for convex function $f$  at $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ as an affine linear map satisfying
$$
f(x) \geq l(x) := f(x_0) + c^T (x - x_0)
$$
for some constant $c \in\mathbb{R}^n$ and for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Note that the tangent may not be unique at $x_0$ e.g. there is a kink in the function at $x_0$.

**Question**: Does there exist a sequence of tangents $(l_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging pointwise to $l$ where $l_i$ is a tangent for $f_i$ at $x_0$ and $l$ is a tangent for $f$ at $x_0$?

My attempt: We know that $f_i(x_0) \to f(x_0)$ from pointwise convergence but I dont know how to show how the gradient converges i.e. $c_i \to c$.

Comment: Your question is confusing since you say "let $l_i$" and then ask "does there exist $l_i$".  I guess you're asking whether there exists a possibly different sequence of tangents $l_i'$ converging to $l$, since clearly $l_i$ itself might not (let $f_i(x) = f(x) =|x|$, take $l_i = 0$ and $l$ some nonzero tangent).  And it's similarly possible that $l_i$ doesn't converge at all.

Comment: @NateEldredge : Yes. Thank you. That is what I am trying to say. I edited the question. Hopefully, it makes more sense.

Comment: So just to check: take $n=1$ and $f(x) = -x^2(x-1)$.  Then $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$, yet if I understand the definition, the tangent line $l(x) = 0$ is *not* a "tangent" in your sense, since we have $f(2) < 0 =l(2)$.  Is that right?  If so then I guess $f$ does not have a "tangent" at 0.

Comment: @NateEldredge : Good point. I edited the question to only consider convex functions to remove this possibility.

Comment: If $n=1$ and all the functions are differentiable convex functions then the tangents are unique. The question becomes the following: if $f_n \to f$ pointwise can we say $f'_n \to f'$ pointwise. I haven't written a counter-example yet, but I think this is false.